# Where is the index file in my forked JSP project?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'v download an open-source jsp project form github.

I have tried many times to upload it to my server and use it.
As the project's readme document toldme ,all I need to do is upoload the folder to my server ,and then visit it by my browser.But,i failed all the times:when i visit the project ,my browser is only blank.

I have done the following steps:1.buy a jsp envoriment server;2.creat a new site which has jsp+tomcat+mysql;3,upload load my jsp project to the site's root;4.buy a domain-name,in my dns provider's admin-page, I bind my domain-name to my jsp server.
But,all i can see is blank!

And I found that ,in my jsp project's  first-stage folder,I couldn't see an index.jsp file. Why? When i did my php-project before,the index.php in the project's first-stage folder is necessary !

Comment: it will be god if you post a  tomcat startup logs

Comment: Ok, let me try this !

Comment: Try to find any log file. Index page name could be probably on WEB-INF/web.xml file.

Comment: I've download the tomcat log file from my server,what should I do next?